# Custom java rule is not applying in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I have implemented a custom rules for java as described in the example project, rule is visible on the server side at rules page, but no one from them is applied to code during analysis. I'm using sonar 5.1.1, I have activated the rule also under a profile and applying the same profile, but no use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).